# What's Maven Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I found this in the book "Jenkins Definitive Guide". I think this is a good thing so I can use this approach to even check all project settings into SVN to recreate the project if required.

As I can't find this in Jenkins plugin, I guess it's a Maven plugin. Can someone point me any document about this? Thanks.

> When configuring a single job with the Maven Jenkins Plugin, you can define all ?>the usual Jenkins configuration elements, such as Maven goals, POM location, >repository URLs, e-mail addresses, number of days to keep the logs, and so on. >The plugin tries to bring you as close to possible to Jenkins’ usual way of >configuring a job manually.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for: http://jenkinsci.github.io/maven-hpi-plugin//

Answer (score 1):

This is not a plugin for Maven. It's a plugin for Jenkins:

[Maven Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin)

> *Jenkins plugin for building Maven 2/3 jobs via a special project type.*
>
> *See [Building a maven2 project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+maven2+project) for more information on how to use this.*